# Difference between "trampoline" methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, trampolines

I've started learning JS recently, and this is my first dive into functional language territory.

Was doing the "trampoline" exercise in the `functional-javascript-workshop` npm module, and came across an interesting difference between my own solution and the official solution. Both work perfectly fine, but I'm at a loss as to what exactly is the practical difference between them. I understand my own solution pretty well, but don't exactly understand why the other one works too.

**My Solution**

```
function repeat(op, num) {
  var _repeat = function() {
    if (num <= 0) return;
    op();
    return repeat(op, --num);
  };

  return _repeat;
}

function trampoline(f) {
  while (f instanceof Function) {
    f = f();
  }
  return f;
}

module.exports = function(op, num) {
  return trampoline(repeat(op, num));
};
```

**Official Solution**

```
function repeat(operation, num) {
  return function() {
    if (num <= 0) return
    operation()
    return repeat(operation, --num)
  }
}

function trampoline(fn) {
  while(fn && typeof fn === 'function') {
    fn = fn()
  }
}

module.exports = function(operation, num) {
  trampoline(function() {
    return repeat(operation, num)
  })
}
```

Specifically, I'm curious about the last part - why does the official solution create an annonymous function instead of just passing `repeat`?

Comment: I don't think there's any difference in code, only thing that I notice is that in official solution you can know right away that trampoline is called with a function, where in your solution, one has to check what are you returning. And on a side note, be careful with this official solutions, avoiding semicolons in javascript might turn out ugly if you don't know this works "under the hood".

Comment: Hey Joel -- I have a question for you. I was hung up on this exercise. I can't see when or if ever "fn && typeof fn === "function" would ever not be true. slightly confused.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the trampoline:

```
   function trampoline(fn) {
      while(fn && typeof fn === 'function') {
        fn = fn()
      }
    }
```

Notice how it keeps iterating as long as`fn` is a function, which it invokes.

So theoretically you can have as many nested functions and get the same result:

```
module.exports = function(operation, num) {
  trampoline(function() {
    return function() {
        return function() {
           return repeat(operation, num);
        };
    };
  });
};
```

**Demo: http://jsbin.com/yixaliyoye/1/edit**

The Official solution has one more redundant step than your solution. No real reason for it, other than the original author probably thought it looked more readable.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a reason.

Except maybe that the trampoline will make the *all* calls, while in your version the first invocation of `repeat` is done outside of it. This might be considered cleaner, and could make an actual difference when `trampoline` was more sophisticated (e.g. wrapping all execution in a try-catch).